# How can I make PowerShell concatenate some command output and a string?

Tags: powershell

Observe:

```
PS Z:\dev> echo $(hg root)\windows
Z:\dev
\windows
PS Z:\dev>
```

I want to see **Z:\dev\windows**. Trying to quote $(hg root) does not help.

**EDIT**

Observe:

```
PS Z:\dev\windows\nc> echo $((hg root).Trim())\Windows
Z:\dev
\Windows
PS Z:\dev\windows\nc> $r = (hg root).Trim()
PS Z:\dev\windows\nc> echo $r\Windows
Z:\dev\Windows
PS Z:\dev\windows\nc> $r = hg root
PS Z:\dev\windows\nc> echo $r\Windows
Z:\dev\Windows
PS Z:\dev\windows\nc>
```

I would like to narrow the scope of my question. I am specifically interested in a one line solution, since this is how I am used to do it in Bash (**echo `hg root`/windows** just works)

**EDIT 2**

```
PS Z:\dev> Write-Host $(hg root)\windows
Z:\dev \windows
PS Z:\dev> Write-Host $((hg root).Trim())\windows
Z:\dev \windows
PS Z:\dev>
```

Write-Host is no good either - note the space between **Z:\dev** and **\windows** in the output.

Comment: Try it with `Write-Host` instead of `echo`. `echo` is an alias to `Write-Output` and will output each item on a separate line, for example.

Comment: No good - edited the post again.

Comment: I'm trying to close this again.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the result of `hg root` includes a newline.

Two possibilities:

```
echo $((hg root).Trim())\Windows

$r = (hg root).Trim()
echo $r\Windows
```

(I would tend to use the latter as it is clearer, especially in scripts.)

#### Additional (based on comment, and extra in question):

It is not clear why the first approach doesn't work, as I don't have Mercurial (I assume) installed. I tried:

```
echo Foo$((Out-String -InputObject "Bar`n").Trim())Bax
```

which gives a one line result:

```
FooBarBax
```

My first thought would be to look very carefully at the output of `hg root` (for example, via a hex dump, such as [PSCX's](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) [Format-Hex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex)).

For a single line solution, recall that the grammar is `$(‹statement list›)`, so the two lines of my second approach can be combined with a pipeline:

```
echo "$(hg root | % {$_.Trim()})\Windows"
```

(also putting the whole argument to [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) (`echo` being an alias) into quotes to make things a little clearer). Or even using two statements:

```
echo "$($a = hg root; $a.Trim())\Windows"
```

Comment: The one line solution does not work, but this is exactly what I am looking for - I have updated my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*.

Apparently, I need to get more sleep:

```
PS Z:\dev> echo "$(hg root)\windows"
Z:\dev\windows
PS Z:\dev>
```

Please, accept my apologies for this question - I had forgotten to try the quotes around the whole expression.